# Algorithm to create "Spot It"/"Dobble" cards, but with two common images from any two cards

Tags: algorithm, math

In the ordinary "Spot It"/"Dobble" game, there is exactly one common image between any two cards. At the moment I am trying to modify the algorithms already available on the internet so that any two cards have two, three, etc. elements in common.

Unfortunately, I have failed and am now looking for ideas on how such an algorithm could look in concrete terms. Do you have any ideas for such an algorithm?
[image]

Comment: Create multiple exactly-one-image-in-common decks and then put one card from each deck onto each super-card?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding what you mean. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: So if you have a deck ABC, ADE, AFG, BDG, BEF, CDF, CEG and a deck abc, ade, afg, bdg, bef, cdf, ceg, then make cards ABCabc, ADEade, AFGafg, BDGbdg, BEFbef, CDFcdf, CEGceg.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that's exactly how I'm implementing it currently. If you play the game a few times, you will know at some point - for example - that image A always comes with image a, image B with b, etc. It would be great, if I could find a way so that the symbols don't always appear in pairs, making the search a little more challenging

Comment: You can shuffle one of the decks though, e.g., ABCbdg, ADEcdf, AFGbef, BDGade, BEFafg, CDFceg, CEGabc.

Comment: This sounds interesting and promising! I will look deeper into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested: I used the advice posted in this comment:

[Algorithm to create "Spot It"/"Dobble" cards, but with two common images from any two cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780880/algorithm-to-create-spot-it-dobble-cards-but-with-two-common-images-from-an#comment116311020_65780880)

So let's assume I take two decks of cards with completely different images.

```
A1     B1
A2     B2
A3     B3
...    ...
An     Bn
```

Now, all those cards get shuffled

```
A23     B50
A4      B12
A18     B17
...     ....
```

and combined into one large card.

```
A23 + B50
A4  + B12
A18 + B17
...   ....
```

This will result in two images matching between each pair of cards (one of set A and one of set B)